# The induced representation of a trivial representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, gelfand-representation

How can I show that the induced representation of a trivial representation of a subgroup is  the permutation representation on its cosets?

Comment: What is your definition of induced representation? Can you go from there?

Answer (score 1):

It's related to that: $G$ acts on $G/H$ by left translations ( a permutation representation), so acts on functions from $G/H$ to the scalars. That is the induced representation $1_H^G$.